# Generating coredump in archlinux

Tags: archlinux, coredump, archlinux-arm

I am trying to debug for my program in Archlinux in embedded board imx8. The program just terminate abruptly after starting up. I am trying to find the core dump to examine. However I could not find the core dump anywhere (tried to find it in /var/lib/systemd/coredump)

I try to follow this link  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/core%20dump. However the link contains only how to disable the link. So I check whether there is disabling of coredump in my board

- Using systemd

I could not find the presence of custom.conf in /etc/systemd/coredump.conf.d/custom.conf. In fact I could not find anything.  So I guess this is not how the core dump is disabled

- Using sysctl

/etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf is not found.

- Using PAM limits

/etc/security/limits.conf could be found. However the whole file is commented (#) and the limits is not found

- Using ulimit

I try to use "ulimit -c unlimited to unset the limits.

However even after checking all this files, there is not any coredump file found in /var/lib/systemd/coredump. So I wonder what I could do.

I tried using coredumpctl list. However it seem that it has not been installed on the board. So I could not use coredumpctl to find the dump file

So I wonder whether there is any settings I should set for release of coredump

Regards

Comment: Try add `ulimit -c unlimited` in `/etc/profile`

Comment: @RadekRojík:  hi thanks for helping...but adding to the /etc/profile does not help..do not see any *.pid files in either current execution directory or in /var/lib/systemd/coredump

Comment: What saying output from `pacman -Qs systemd-coredump`?

Comment: @RadekRojík : pacman: command not found... the archlinux in the board is based on yocto sumo distribution

Comment: I see! And this instructions: https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/enable-and-analyze-coredumps-in-linux Maybe the same solution.

Comment: Does your program have a signal handler? If you consume a signal that would lead to a core dump, and bring down your process afterwards gracefully, a core dump will not be generated. So I've read sorting out my coredump issues in the last week.